# CSS - Pool Survey form

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am trying to make something like this:

**How it should look:**

[image]

**How it actualy looks:**

[image]

**CSS**

```
h1{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.bar{           
    width:170px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 17px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.progress{
    background-image: url("images/survey_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    height: 17px;
}

.label{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="progress" style="width:75%;">65%</div>
</div>
<div class="label">Dominik !</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="progress" style="width:20%;">20%</div>
</div>
<div class="label">Jenda</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="progress" style="width:15%;">15%</div>
</div>
<div class="label">Lojza</div>
```

You see the difference, its in text color but mostly on position of that number of  %
Can somebody help me to fix it? I try to padding/margin that text but just cant fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colour can be solved just by adding `color:#fff`, not really a big issue.

As for the positioning, try adding `line-height:17px` (ie. matching your `height`). This will cause it the centre the text vertically on the bar.

Comment: Yea mate color was not that big problem just it was difference between original and my one, so i wrote it down. line-height: 17px; in .progress will not help :(

Comment: @user3009924 remove `height: 17px` from  `.bar` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the `padding:5px;` in `.progress{}` and add `color:white;`

```
.progress{
    background-image: url("images/survey_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding:5px;          /* delete this */
    text-align: right;
    height: 17px;
    color:#fff;     /* add this */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9c9wR/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things around to get this working.

- Removed the padding from .progress as that would just overflow the div
- Changed text color to white
- Added line-height: 17px; to .progress to vertically center the div
- Added a space after .progress so the text wasn't right at the edge of the div

Here's the new CSS

```
.bar{           
    width:170px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 17px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.progress{
    background-image: url("images/survey_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.progress:after {
    content: "\00a0";
}

.label{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the padding. This is causing the error.

```
padding:0;
```